# How to parse HTML elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am looking to extract items listed under 'Categories' from a list of Github webpages.

In the sample code, I was able to identify the chunk of text that I need to parse but when I parse the text, the output looks like this:

```
['\n\n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n ', '\n\n  Continuous integration\n\n\n  Security\n\n']
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
[Continuous integration, Security]
```

How can I change my `get_text()` line of code to get to the final result?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

websites = ['https://github.com/marketplace/actions/yq-portable-yaml-processor','https://github.com/marketplace/actions/TruffleHog-OSS']

for links in websites:
URL = requests.get(links)
detailsoup = BeautifulSoup(URL.content, "html.parser")

categories = detailsoup.findAll('div', {'class': 'ml-n1 clearfix'})
print(categories)
categoriesList = [categories.get_text() for categories in categories]
print(categoriesList)

# keep only 1st element & maintain type as list
categoriesList = categoriesList[1:2]
if not categoriesList:
    categoriesList.insert(0, 'Error')
```

Comment: `get_text()` has `strip=True` - but you can always use `for`-loop with `.strip()` (and other functions) to modify your list.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add parameter `strip=True`:

```
categoriesList = [categories.get_text(strip=True) for category in categories]
```

Also try to select your elements more specific:

```
categories = detailsoup.find_all('a', {'class': 'topic-tag'})
```

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

websites = ['https://github.com/marketplace/actions/yq-portable-yaml-processor','https://github.com/marketplace/actions/TruffleHog-OSS']

for links in websites:
    URL = requests.get(links)
    detailsoup = BeautifulSoup(URL.content, "html.parser")

    categories = detailsoup.find_all('a', {'class': 'topic-tag'})
    categoriesList = [categories.get_text(strip=True) for category in categories]
    print(categoriesList)
```